# Class forward declaration in C++

Tags: c++

How to correctly forward declare classes ?. If I try this it won't compile:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

class B ;

class A
{
    public:
    B returnB()
    {
        return B() ;
    }
} ;

class B
{
    public:
    A returnA()
    {
        return A() ;
    }
} ;

int main(void)
{

    getch() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't the forward-declaration. The problem is using an incomplete type where a complete type is needed.

Comment: I don't exactly understand You. Can You correct the code for me ?

Comment: Your forward declaration is fine, but this is not a scenario in which forward declaration is sufficient. Check your book again, then  correct it yourself! :)

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the compile error that you're getting.

Comment: @Component10: Nah, we don't need it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Shh, don't discourage the act of doing so. Even if it isn't necessary here, I'd rather have spurious ones than missing the ones that are necessary.

Comment: @chris: I agree with that. I just don't agree that it'll actually help us answer in this case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't possess psychic powers I'm afraid!

Comment: @Component10: Oh, you haven't got those yet? Don't worry it'll come

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In the meantime, could you post me a solution to the compile error I'll get at 11:37am tomorrow? :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Definitely, but you know how things wear off and how one could take that to mean we never need their error. It's all too likely to happen, sadly.

Comment: @Component10: I have it drafted. I'll post it at 11.38am to avoid disrupting the space-time continuum any more than I do by simply existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes there are scenarios where you must define your functions outside of the class:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    B returnB();
};

class B
{
public:
    A returnA();
};

B A::returnB()
{
    return B();
}

A B::returnA()
{
    return A();
}
```

Usually the definition (implementation) goes inside a separate *.cpp file. If it is in a header, then it has to be `inline`.